# pytest: How to DRY up similar model manager method tests

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

### What I have

#### Manager and Model

With the manager I can get those cases that are fulfilled, caducated or prescribed.

```py
from datetime import date

class CaseManager(models.Manager):
    """Define a manager for Case model."""

    def fulfilled(self):
        """Get all cases that will fulfill soon."""
        return self.get_queryset().filter(fulfillment=date.today())

    def caducated(self):
        """Get all cases that will caducate soon."""
        return self.get_queryset().filter(caducity=date.today())

    def prescribed(self):
        """Get all cases that will prescribe soon."""
        return self.get_queryset().filter(prescription=date.today())

class Case(models.Model):
    """Representation of a legal case."""

    fulfillment = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Fulfillment"), default=date.today)
    caducity = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Caducity"), default=date.today)
    prescription = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("Prescription"), default=date.today)

    objects = CaseManager()
```

#### Factory

Create fake cases for testing.

```py
class CaseFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    """Define Case Factory"""

    fulfillment = Faker("date")
    caducity = Faker("date")
    prescription = Faker("date")

    class Meta:
        model = Case
```

### What I've tried

#### Tests

```
class TestCasesManagers:
    def test_fulfilled(self):
        case = CaseFactory(fulfillment=date.today())
        assert case in Case.objects.fulfilled()

    def test_caducated(self):
        case = CaseFactory(caducity=date.today())
        assert case in Case.objects.caducated()

    def test_prescribed(self):
        case = CaseFactory(prescription=date.today())
        assert case in Case.objects.prescribed()
```

### Problem

With this approach I have to repeat almost the same test for all the methods of my manager that are similar which is not scalable.

### What I want

1. Create `cases` and change the keyword args that are passed to the factory to create a fake model.
2. Call the different methods of the manager in `assert` without repeating the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalize these with a list of object:

```
class TestCasesManagers:
    kws = [
        ('fulfillment', 'fulfilled'),
        ('caducity', 'caducated'),
        ('prescription', 'prescribed')
    ]

    def make_test(ky, mg):
        def f(self):
            case = CaseFactory(**{ky: date.today()})
            assert case in getattr(Case.objects, mg)()
        return f
    for ky, mg in kws:
        locals()[f'test_{mg}'] = make_test(ky, mg)
    del make_test
```

You can thus easily add an extra 2-tuple to the list `kws` to test this combination as well. These are still *individual* tests, so you can decide to run only test *one* of the manager functions, or only retry the failed ones.

Comment: Why you use this line `del make_test`? What is its purpose?